# How can I post to WordPress.com via Tor?

Tags: wordpress.com, tor

I decided to go all cryptopunk and start a blog via Tor. I thought using WordPress was practically traditional. However, when I try to save a draft or make a post, the button is pressed but the whirler keeps whirling forever, and the post never gets saved/made. I tried posting to the support forum, but the content of that post was lost.

Is there any way to post to WordPress.com using Tor?

I have tried Tumblr, Diaspora, etc, and I can post there. However, I would prefer to use WordPress.com

Answer (score 2):

Tor Browser has some JavaScript disabled by default. Go into options for the NoScript plugin and add WordPress.com to your Whitelist and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try clearing all cache and cookies of your present browser and retry. Else, install Opera and enable turbo mode while browsing. This should get WordPress to work fine again.

Comment: my browser is the Tor browser (i.e. modified Firefox) - is there a version of Opera that uses Tor?

Comment: I think this one is it http://operator.en.softonic.com/

Comment: This isn't officially supported by The Tor Project and should not be considered safe. It also hasn't been updated since 2010.